# Update my session variables

Tags: javascript, php, session

How do I update my session variables without having to log out?

I have this session array that has to be updated:

```
$data_for_analog_meter = $_SESSION['data_for_analog_meter'];
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Currently you "update" `$data_for_analog_meter`, not the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't forget to `session_start()` when you update it, I assume that you started it at the top of that page, and then:

```
  $_SESSION['name'] = 'NEW VALUE';
```

Answer (score 1):

you're assigning session value to variable, you need to do the reverse, to update session value you need to do:

```
$_SESSION['data_for_analog_meter'] = $data_for_analog_meter;
```